# How to get the html code of an element that appears only when hovering using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I need to get the html code of an element that appears only when hovering, but I can't even find this element in the developer console, and I still need to parse the values from it
https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/brazil/serie-a/esporte-clube-juventude-fortaleza-fRDuTQ2O/#ah;2;0.00;0

[image]

This element appears when you hover over the location

Comment: Please let me know if my answer worked and if there are any more questions about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the tool-tip element appearing on hovering can by uniquely located by `id='tooltiptext'`.
To hover over element you can use `action_chains`.
For example, if you want to hover over element located by css_selector `div.my_class` you can do this:

```py
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.my_class')  #get the element
actions.move_to_element(element).perform() #move to the element, hover over it
tool_tip_text = driver.find_element_by_id('tooltiptext').text #get the tool-tip element and extract it's text
```

You will need to include

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

And to initialize the `actions` object with

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
```